# siunitx: µ not rendering properly

Tags: siunitx

I've recently started using siunitx and have a small problem with the letter µ. It does not seem to render properly and looks quite pixelated while the rest is perfectly fine.

Here's a MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\SI{1}{\um}
\end{document}
```

That's what I get as a result:
[image]

Does anyone have an idea what might cause that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What is your distribution?

Comment: For me on latest TeX Live the micro symbol renders just fine.

Comment: I'm using MiKTeX, version 2.9.6800.

Comment: The  `μ` is pixellated because  the compiler doen't find the postscript (vector)  fonts, so it uses bitmap fonts (`Type 3` in postscript parlance). Run `MiKTeX Console` (Admin mode), and in the `Tasks` menu, select `Refresh font map files` to update the database of postscript fonts.

Comment: That doesn't seem to make a difference but thanks for the suggestion. In case the information helps, nu for example works fine.

Comment: But the μ as a symbol for `micro` is not the standard mu. It is an upright mu, with a small serif at the bottom. I don't know from which font it is taken.

Comment: It seems the `\micro` symbol is just the `\textmu` glyph from `textcomp`.

Comment: Is the cm-super package installed?

Comment: No, it wasn't. It is now and solved the problem. Thanks a lot!